# How do I get the co-ordinates of a mouse click on a transformed WPF control?

Tags: wpf

I'm playing with a simple WPF application. One part of it includes a grid containing several controls. The grid is rotated using a LayoutTransform and a RotateTransform. I need to get the co-ordinates of a mouse-click relative to the top-left of the grid, taking the rotation into account.

To be clear, let's say I have a single drawing surface within the grid and no transform had been applied. I then click at location X = 20, Y = 10 and put a dot on the drawing surface at that point. If the grid is now rotated by 30 degrees and I click on the dot (which is also moved by the rotation), the click position should still be X = 20, Y = 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MouseEventArgs has a [GetPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventargs.getposition(v=VS.100).aspx) method that takes a UIElement. It returns the position of the mouse event relative to the specified element. So if you want to transform a mouse click into coordinates of a grid, pass that grid to the GetPosition method.

Comment: Perfect! I'm actually using MouseDown but MouseButtonEventArgs has the method too. Sure I tried this before but my brain must have been on autopilot. Many thanks.

Comment: ...maybe I was rotating something in the grid and checking the grid. It'll be something stupid.